# How do I adjust model parameters to get stable oscillations with Arditi-Ginzburg equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am using the predator-prey equations from the Arditi-Ginzburg to model the interactions of 14 species in a video game.  The equations for two species are:
$$
dx=x(A-Bx)-Cxy/(x+y)\\
dy=-Gy+Mxy/(x+y)
$$
with careful selection of parameters A,B,C,G,M I get the expected out-of-phase oscillations between the two species, but there is a damping factor.  See [the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkpAD.jpg).

A,B: controls the growth of the prey w/o predator

C controls how fast the predator consumes the prey

G controls how fast the predator dies w/o prey

M controls how fast the predator grows with maximum prey

How can I adjust the parameters to make the oscillations continue indefinitely?  Stable systems are very common, and damped oscillations are common.  Where are the infinite oscillations?

P.S. Most choices for parameters quickly result in a stable system.. why?

Edit: With lots of tweaking, here are repeating cycles, with growing amplitude, see [plot](https://imgur.com/E62f09I).

Increasing parameter A from 0.21 to 0.23 and then increasing parameter C from 0.7 to 0.82 made the difference.  The slightly increasing amplitude can be adjusted by increasing Parameter G very slightly.

Now the peaks are fine, but the valleys are too low and too long.  I am using LibreOffice to synthesize and visualize this.  Can you guys recommend better open source tools for hacking functions?

Comment: The second plot uses starting conditions: X=1000 (population of grass) Y=100 (population of mice) and parameters are A=0.23 B=0.00001 C=0.82 G=0.53 and M=0.7.    I just added a second predator, so I will post those results as well.

Comment: As far as tools, I am thinking of something that will make it easier to explore the visualization of the equations.  LibreOffice is ok, but I keep finding copy errors in my equations, and scaling for graphing is tedious.  I used MathCAD a dozen years ago, but have not kept up with it.  Mathematica was always the package I wanted, but it was always too expensive.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

I added one more predator to the mix.

$$
dx=x(A-Bx)-Cxy/(x+y)\\
dy=-Gy+Mxy/(x+y)-C1yz/(y+z)\\
dz=-G1y+M1yz/(y+z)
$$
dx= change in grass population

dy= change in mice population

dz= change in fox population

Starting Parameters:

X=1000 Y=1000 Z=100
A= 0.23 B=0.00001 C=0.82 G=0.53 M=0.71 C1=0.42 G1=0.4 M1=0.71

[The plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI84C.jpg) shows the basic out-of-phase relationships are starting to emerge, and the populations are headed towards a steady state.  A little more tweaking should get these three into steady oscillations, and then I will continue adding to the food chain...

Comment: With all these questions you should try find fixed point solutions that will give an idea of the solution behaviour..in this case you should set $\dot{x}=\dot{y}=\dot{z}=0$ and then find the $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy that criterion. This will help with the insight into the parameter choice i.e. which parameter choices lead to stable solutions, limit cycles etc etc